# custom logging under pm2

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2

I have some useful logging in my node app that I write to `console.log`

```
node server.js >> /var/log/nodeserver.log 2>&1
```

However, when trying the same under **pm2**:

```
pm2 start server.js >> /var/log/pm2server.log 2>&1
```

the log file only shows the **pm2** startup information

Is application logging at all possible with **pm2**?  On their page they discuss logging, and show an image with text like `"log message from echo.js"`, but I see nothing about getting custom information into the **pm2** log.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When running with pm2 your application logs will reside in `$HOME/.pm2/logs` as described [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#pm2-configuration-folder-structure). Verifying this locally with a simple `index.js` file that outputs `console.log('test')`

```
$ pm2 start index.js
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting index.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory     │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ index    │ 0  │ fork │ 36976 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 9.258 MB   │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

Notice how I see no `console.log` output here, **but**, if I navigate to `$HOME/.pm2/logs` I see

```
logs $ ls
index-error-0.log   index-out-0.log

logs $ cat index-out-0.log
test
```

Comment: Can we change log path?

Comment: You sure can, have a look at [the list of options here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#options), particularly `-l`, `-o`, and `-e`

Comment: Yeah! I got them later. Thanks

Comment: I don't want to write out info logs to file. I only want to keep logging on console in production, no file should be created , how to do that with pm2 ?

Answer (score 5):

One nifty feature is to use the [`logs`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#cheat-sheet) feature in terminal:

```
pm2 logs [--raw]
```

this will live stream the all the logs. Other handy commands are:

- `pm2 flush`
- `pm2 reloadLogs`

Answer (score 3):

Update in 2017.

Define log path as parameter when pm2 command is executed (`-l`, `-o`, `-e`) is very easy to use and normally is the best choice.

However, if you don't want to define log path every time when pm2 is executed, you can generate a configuration file, define `error_file` and `out_file`, and start pm2 from that:

1. Generate a configuration file: `pm2 ecosystem simple`. This would generate a file `ecosystem.config.js`, with following content:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     apps : [{
       name   : "app1",
       script : "./app.js"
     }]
   }
   ```
2. Define `error_file` (for error log) and `out_file` (for info log) in the file, such as:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     apps : [{
       name   : "app1",
       script : "./app.js",
       error_file : "./err.log",
       out_file : "./out.log"
     }]
   }
   ```
3. Start the process from the configuration file:

   ```
   pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
   ```

In this way, the logs are saved to `./err.log` and `./out.log`.

Please refer to the [document](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#log-files) for detail information.

Answer (score 0):

In case of new start, you just:

- run `pm2 start/reload ecosystem.config.js [--only your_app]`

But when it is already started (pm2 already managing it) you have to do (someone can find a better way, but this works for me):

- run `pm2 delete your_app`
- run `pm2 start`