# fs.writeFile fails without error when writing to a specific (not full) partition

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I'm implementing an image cache for favicons found on the web. At one point I have the favicon's URL, and I'm sending it to my page, everything is fine.

Now alongside this, I write the icon to disk, using a pseudo-unique filename that I construct using the URL components.

And this works too, but **only if I write to `/tmp/`!?**

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/favicon', function(req, res) {
  favicon(req.query.url, function(err, iconUrl) {
    if (iconUrl) {
      var u = Url.parse(iconUrl);
      request.get({url: iconUrl}, function (err, response, body) {
        if (!err && typeof body !== 'undefined') {
          var h = u.host.replace(/\//g, ''),
              p = u.path.replace(/\//g, ''),
              fileName;

          fileName = path.join('/tmp', h + '.' + p);
          // fileName = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'cache', h + '.' + p);

          fs.writeFile(fileName, body, function(err) {
            if(err)
              console.log(err);
            else
              console.log("SAVED! (%s)", fileName);
          });
        } else {
          console.log('### ERROR iconUrl: (%s) err: (%s)', iconUrl, err);
        }
      });
      res.send(iconUrl);
    } else {
      res.status(500).send('No icon found');
    }
  });
});
```

This is called on the client (web browser) side like this:

```
$.get("/favicon", {
  url: decodeURI(feedHost),
  dataType: "json",
  timeout: 2000
}, function(iconURL) {
  console.info('OK (icon: %s)', iconURL);
}).done(function(iconURL) {
  console.info('OK (icon: %s)', iconURL);
}).fail(function() {
  console.error('ERROR');
});
```

I though it was a "disk full" problem but no, here is the partition table on this machine, the project directory (where my image cache directory resides) in inside the `/home` partition, and `/tmp/` is, well, on `/`:

```
# df -h   
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           388M  6.3M  382M   2% /run
/dev/sda6        19G   14G  3.8G  79% /
tmpfs           1.9G   23M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/core/4206
/dev/loop1      128M  128M     0 100% /snap/shotcut/20
/dev/loop2       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/core/4110
/dev/loop3       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/core/4017
/dev/loop4      298M  298M     0 100% /snap/shotcut/17
/dev/loop5      128M  128M     0 100% /snap/shotcut/21
/dev/sda5       121G  102G   14G  89% /home
tmpfs           388M   12K  388M   1% /run/user/1000
```

So when I use the code above, everything works fine, and `/tmp/` fills with images, asynchronously, perfect.

As soon as I remove the leading `/` of the file path - pointing to a valid path, of course - then one, two, maximum 3 favicons are copied and then the process fails somehow, triggering the `.fail()` method one the client side, but *without any error on the server*.

Help!

Questions:

- What could be causing this weird "write 2 or 3 files then stop" problem? NB: The server is launched with [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).
- Is my ajax call (JQuery `$.get()`) correct? Why does it make the other ajax calls in the page fail, instead of gently erroring and then move on?

### UPDATE

It turns out that I was not saving a correct image file in `/tmp/` ; I am now using this code:

```
router.get('/favicon', function(req, res) {

  favicon(req.query.url, function(err, iconUrl) {
    if (iconUrl) {

      if (!iconUrl.startsWith('..') && Url.parse(iconUrl)) {

        var u = Url.parse(iconUrl),
            h = u.host.replace(/\//g, ''),
            p = u.path.replace(/\//g, ''),
            fileName;

        fileName = path.join('/tmp/cache', h + '.' + p);
        // fileName = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'cache', h + '.' + p);

        let stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        stream.on('finish', function () {
          console.log("SAVED %s (%s)", fileName, iconUrl);
        }).on('error', function (err) {
          console.log("NOT SAVED %s (%s)", fileName, err);
        });
        request(iconUrl).pipe(stream);

      } else {
        console.log('iconUrl NOT OK: (%s)', iconUrl);
      }

      res.send(iconUrl);
    } else {
      res.status(500).send('No icon found');
    }
  });
});
```

And now the files saved are proper image files ; However the problem persists, and I have now tested this code on **several other (Linux) machines** including a production web server, same thing! No way to save (more than a handful of) files within the project repo, and yet if I use `/tmp/*` as the file path, everything is fine!

This is rendering me crazy, please put me out of this misery :|

### Update 2

I managed to write to my home partition. The only place I cannot write to is **any directory inside (and including) the project directory**.

Comment: It looks like that fileName contains some special chars.
Can you add console.log(fileName) and see with which file it fails?

Comment: Hi Alex ; When I do this, I get the names of the 2 or 3 files that I also can see in the cache, and they are all named `subdomain.domain.tld.filename.extension`. But again, no error is triggered anywhere :( Bear in mind that when I use `/tmp/` the same files are copied fine.

Comment: Hm, okay, I don't see if you dump error if any... can you add if (err) console.error(err) after function(err, response, body) { ?

Comment: I also ran various tests where `fileName` was just `Math.random()` but same result: `/tmp` fine, local repo path fail :(

Comment: Yes, Alex, I *am* testing `body` for errors. And no need to test `request.get()` too, as it is not failing. I mean, if I remove the whole `if (!err && typeof body !== 'undefined')` everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out. The culprit is [the pm2 watcher](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/), that restarts the server when something is written within the whole scope of the project.

That's the (hard to find, if it's written somewhere I don't know where) reason why I could write my image files **everywhere on the disk *but* in the project directory** without any error, just a slow and chaotic collapsing of the server ; Thank you for your patience.

So I created the following pm2 process management file (by running `pm2 ecosystem simple` thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45955213/1729094))

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"            : "petrolette",
    "script"          : "./bin/www",
    "watch"           : true,
    "ignore_watch"    : ["favicons-cache"],
    "log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    "env": {
      "PORT": 8666,
      "FAVICONS_CACHE_DIR": "favicons-cache"
    },
    "env_production" : {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  }]
}
```

So now my `favicons-cache` dir is protected from the watch process, and as a bonus its name is now an `ENV` var so I can access it with `process.env.FAVICONS_CACHE_DIR` :)